# Build Failure of Apache Beam 2.6.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: apache-beam

I am Facing Issue While Building master Node of Apache beam 2.6.0-SNAPSHOT and Getting Error :

```
Failed to execute goal com.igormaznitsa:mvn-golang-wrapper:2.1.7:build (go-build-linux-amd64)

Can't find generated target file : C:\Users\KishanK\Desktop\2.5.0\Updated\beam\sdks\go\target\linux_amd64\beamctl -> [Help 1]
```

I am Facing problem from Last Few Weeks Build Always get Failed on Go SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting the issue. I also see the problem on my machine and opened a bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-4724

Note that Beam has migrated its build system from Maven to Gradle and Maven support is in the process of being removed. The error happens with Maven only and why it seems to have gone unnoticed. The simplest path forward is to build with Gradle instead, i.e., "./gradlew build".

Henning